# Open Custom List form in Popup Window

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a webpart .I have a grid view with templatefield . I want open Custom Listfrom in popup window. 
I use this code in  LinkButtonClick

```
  PostBackUrl="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ url: '../Lists/GBE/NewForm.aspx', title: 'User Survey' }); return false;"
```

but don't run!

I use the following code in Hyperlink

```
  NavigateUrl="javascript:OpenPopUpPageWithTitle('addressurl',RefreshonDialogClose,400,600,'')"
```

this Oepn popup , but when use this code for LinkButton , Don't run!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog... for using the SharePoint Modal dialog.. Check the sample code below...

```
function OpenModalDialog() {
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.width = 500;
options.height = 250;
options.url = "/_layouts/MyPage.aspx";
options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(
                    null, portal_modalDialogClosedCallback);
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);}
```

Comment: Please read my update.i use this code but don't run .

Comment: did u include sp.js???

Comment: yes, I add <script>

Comment: Check by adding this in your page <SharePoint:ScriptLink runat="server" Name="sp.js" OnDemand="true" Localizable="false" />

Comment: Yes ,I add this code.